# How to set the textfield value to picker in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which I have a textfield where I am displaying values in it from database. There is a button besides the textfield. I have picker which contain 4 values in it viz Custom,Walk,Run,Jog.

If the textfield contains a value i.e if contains 'Walk' in it then on the click of button I am showing the picker with the 4 values populated in it. But my problem is when the button is clicked the value 'Walk' should be set on the picker.

This is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    currentarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Custom",@"Walk",@"Run",@"Jog",nil];
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

This is my button action which when clicked will open the picker:

```
-(IBAction)choose
{
    actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:[currentarray objectAtIndex:0] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [actionsheet setTitle:@"Picker"];

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
    pickerView.dataSource=self;
    pickerView.delegate=self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
    [actionsheet addSubview:pickerView];
    [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
    [pickerView selectRow:[txtTextfield.text intValue ]-1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];        
    [actionsheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow]];
    [actionsheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];        
}

-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{      
    NSString *string;
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[currentarray objectAtIndex:row]];
    return string;      
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [currentarray count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the pickerView like this,

```
 [pickerView setObject:textField.text];
```

have a look on the following link,

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11594-set-selected-row-of-uipickerview-in-applicationdidfinishlaunching.html